# Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint - IdentityServer4 ASP.Net Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, token, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, identityserver3

[image]

The connect/token is working good by using swagger, but when I'm trying to use it in postman, an error is showing

```
{
 "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

The `Status code: 400 Bad Request.`

How to fix this issue?

Comment: In postman, did you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?